# Activar boton dependiendo de caja de texto

Tags: c#

Tengo este código para activar un botón dependiendo de unos campos de texto. Al compilar este código no realiza la función. No habilita el botón cuando escribo en el campo de texto.

¿Podría alguien ayudarme cual es el problema que tengo?.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  this.LoadUI(); 
  table2.Visible=false;
  Opciones.Visible=false;

  if (txtLote.Text == "  "){
      buttonPRB.Enabled = false;
      btnFinal.Enabled  = false;
      btnParada.Enabled = false;
      btnenLotes.Enabled = false;
  }

  else {
      buttonPRB.Enabled = true;
      btnFinal.Enabled  = true;
      btnParada.Enabled = true;
      btnenLotes.Enabled = true;

      }
   }
```

Código caja de texto:

```
<td> 
   <asp:Label ID="labelOF" Text="O.F." class="Info_Label" runat="server" /> 
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtOF" class=" Input_Grande cmp" runat="server"/> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás intentando controlar un evento que se produce con la página cargada en la acción de carga de la misma. Esa condición que tienes puesta te valdría para comprobar, en la carga de la página (`Page_Load`) si tienes que activar o no los botones en función de los datos que obtuvieses de base de datos o enviados a la página desde otro formulario.

Dicho esto, para comprobar si tienes que habilitar un botón en base a si la caja de texto tiene o no valor puedes utilizar el evento `TextBox.TextChanged`. Además es más correcto utilizar el método de `String.IsNullOrEmpty` para comprobar si el cuadro de texto está vacío

Para utilizarlo con tu código sería de la siguiente manera:

```
protected void txtLote_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLote.Text)){
         buttonPRB.Enabled = false;
         btnFinal.Enabled  = false;
         btnParada.Enabled = false;
         btnenLotes.Enabled = false;
     }
     else {
         buttonPRB.Enabled = true;
         btnFinal.Enabled  = true;
         btnParada.Enabled = true;
         btnenLotes.Enabled = true;
     }  
}
```

**EDIT: Tras tu comentario** (que he agregado a tu pregunta)

Te falta agregar en el código ASP de la caja de texto el `handler` para que ejecute el método `TextChanged`.

Tendrías que tener tu caja de texto así (fíjate en el `OnTextChanged="txtLote_TextChanged"`):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOF" class="Input_Grande cmp" OnTextChanged="txtLote_TextChanged" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Hola, la función sigue sin funcionar. Al estar trabajando bajo una plataforma (traksys 8) podría tener algún dificultad al compilar este código?

Comment: ¿Has creado el método únicamente o también le has agregado el handler a la acción de la caja de texto? No conozco traksys, podría ser...

Comment: Si lo tengo creado. El problema es que no me identifica el id del html que le he puesto.

Comment: ¿Puedes actualizar la pregunta con el código de la página asp? Al menos lo correspondiente a la caja de texto

Comment: <td>
                          <asp:Label   ID="labelOF" Text="O.F." class="Info_Label" 
                           runat="server" />
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtOF" class=" Input_Grande cmp"   
                           runat="server"/>
                      </td>

Comment: Gracias con eso me ha funcionado

Comment: De nada! Haz el favor entonces de marcar la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza mejor el ***Is null or empty*** de la clase String

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLote.Text))
{
      buttonPRB.Enabled = false;
      btnFinal.Enabled  = false;
      btnParada.Enabled = false;
      btnenLotes.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
      buttonPRB.Enabled = true;
      btnFinal.Enabled  = true;
      btnParada.Enabled = true;
      btnenLotes.Enabled = true;

}
```

Comment: Hola el código no me ha funcionado al compilarlo sigue sin realizarme nada. Estoy trabajando en una interfaz del traksys 8 por lo tanto tengo muchas pegas con esto. Gracias igualmente